# Git changes line endings from "LF" to "CRLF". Can this cause any problems?

Tags: pdftex, git

I am using GitHub to manage my Latex project. When I want to commit my .tex files, git will change the line endings from "LF"  to "CRLF".

Can this cause any kind of problems?

I use MiKTex and Texmaker on Windows, if this is helpful in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not aware of any problems, but [you can configure `git` to change line endings or not](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings) with the command

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

You can also declare `.tex`, `.dtx`, `.cls`, etc. as text files and declare how their line endings will be handled in `.gitattributes`.  Adding a line like

```
*.tex text
```

will tell `git` that all files with the `tex` extension should have their line ends converted, to LF on Linux/UNIX or CRLF on Windows.  Conversely, the line

```
*.tex text eol=lf
```

tells `git` that a `.tex` file should keep its UNIX line ends even on Windows.

Comment: Thank you! Really nice and very helpful answer!! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Can this cause any kind of problems?

> I’m not aware of any problems,

If you work alone with `Git`, it should be fine. However, once you start cloning, i.e. sharing your repository with others, it can be a problem, as diffent operating systems do treat the end of line differently. Think of 3 people working with your data on `windows`, `Linux` and `iOS`. See configuration in @Davislor 's reply, so `Git` can handle this for you.

You may also want to add the file `.gitignore` in you working directory. E.g. when you enter:

```
# files to ignore
*

# files NOT to ignore (exceptions to aboves rule)
!*.tex
```

`git` will leave out all `.aux`, `.pdf`, `.log` files etc. You do want this, because one day somebody will have to merge different versions, add Git will spot differences in **any** file. While you'd like to do this for the `.tex` files, you don't want to adjust the `.pdf` on binary level, do you ? ;-)

It's good to remind oneself from time to time, that `Git` is about version control, not about backup. So if you need a `.pdf` from different releases, handle them outside of `Git`, e.g. by storing them in a directory, which you exclude by `.gitignore` :)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you :) I've already setup my .gitignore. That's a good point with the .pdf, I will keep that in mind.